# Line break as html select option value

Tags: html

I have a select box and want to offer a line break value

```
<select>
    <option value=";">Semicolon</option>
    <option value=",">Comma</option>
    <option value=".">Dot</option>
    <option value="\">Backslash</option>
    <option value="?">Linebreak</option>
</select>
```

Now what to set as actual html value for the line break?

Note: Doing a real line break in the source code is not an option.

Comment: Personally, I just would map strings to values for the whole thing. Example: `linebreak` => `\n`

Comment: you don't have to use special characters as values. You could use some kind of logical names, and decipher it when you are processing it.

Comment: \n ? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Replacing server-side is always possible. This question is specifically on doing it client-side.

Comment: Perhaps you could give us an example of what you are using this for. It might help better answer your question.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst Sounds like an answer to me... Here's is your fiddle to back it up: http://jsfiddle.net/rCgKg/ But perhaps the OP needs to clarify what "real line break" means...

Comment: @Austin Brunkhorst, Wesley Murch: &#10; does it, thanks. Please post as answer so i can accept.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Is that jQuery you used in the fiddle?

Comment: Yes. He loaded & used jQuery 2.02 in the "Frameworks & Extensions" section in the upper left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `&#10;` character. I'm posting this from my initial comment.